# Probability Problem from Ross's 'A First Course in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I've been working on a problem from Ross's "A First Course in Probability" and I'd like some guidance on my solution.

**Problem:**
A newsboy buys papers for 10 cents each and sells them for 15 cents each. He cannot return any unsold papers. Given that his daily demand follows a binomial distribution with parameters n = 10 and p = 1/3, approximately how many papers should he purchase to maximize his expected profit?

**My Attempt:**
Let's define the following:

```
P: Profit
S: Sales
B: Newspapers bought
```

The expected profit is given by:

```
E[P] 15*min(E[S],B) - 10*B
```

Using the binomial expectation:

```
E[S] = n*p = 10*(1/3) = 10/3
```

Based on this, we have three scenarios:

```
1) If E[S] > B:
E[P] = 15*B - 10*B
Given E[S] = 10/3 is greater than B,
E[P] = 5*B < 50/3

2) If E[S] < B:
E[P] = 15*E[S] - 10*(B - E[S]) = 25*E[S] - 10*B
Given E[S] = 10/3 is less than B,
E[P] = 25*E[S] - 10*B < 150/3

3) If E[S] = B:
E[P] = 15*B = 15*E[S]
Given E[S] = 10/3 is equal to B,
E[P] = 15*B = 50
```

From the above, it seems the optimal strategy would be to purchase newspapers in the amount equal to the expected sales, which is approximately 3 newspapers.

Have I approached this problem correctly?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but there are problems with your approach.It must always be true that $E(p) < 5B$ because you can never make more than 5 cents per paper and there is a non zero probability that you make zero sales.

Comment: It is true that
$$E[p] = E[ \min(S, B)] - 10B$$
But it does NOT follow that 
$$E[p] =  \min( E[S] , B) - 10B$$
You will need to need to do explicit sums of the form...
$$E[p] = \sum_{k=1}^B kP(k) + B \bigg( \sum_{k=B+1}^{10} P(k) \bigg) -10B$$
where
$$P(k) \equiv \binom {10}k (\frac 13)^k (\frac 23)^{10-k} $$

Comment: Got it! Many thanks, it helped me a lot! How can I like your comment? Sorry I'm new here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected profit is given by
$$
\mathbb E[\text{Profit}] = \mathbb E[p( q\wedge D)] - cq
$$
where $D$ is a random variable with distribution $F$ representing demand, $p=15$ is the price each unit is sold for, $c=10$ is the price each unit is bought for, and $q$ is the mnumber of units stocked. The value of $q$ that maximises the above is given by
$$
q^* = F^{-1}\left(\frac{p-c}p\right),
$$
where $F^{-1}$ denotes the generalised inverse distribution function of $D$. Since here $D$ is discrete, we find that $q^* = 3$, as $F(2)<\frac{p-c}p=\frac13\leqslant F(3)$.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!